# Auto Increment value required, but why?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert some data into a MySQL table using python. From my understanding, when you insert data into a table that has a column that auto increments, you don't need to give the values of said column. However, I am running into an issue where I don't have enough values required to insert data. What am I doing wrong? I've looked on this site, w3schools, the MySQL docs, and it looks like I'm doing everything right. I am getting error: `mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

```
...
HAND_HISTORY_DB_TABLES['Hands'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `Hands` ("
    "   `HandID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
    "   `HandNumber` int UNIQUE,"
    "   `HandDate` date NOT NULL,"
    "   `HandResults` float"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
...
            hand_insert = "INSERT INTO Hands "\
                          "SELECT %s, %s, %s " \
                          "FROM Hands " \
                          "WHERE NOT EXISTS " \
                          "(SELECT NULL, HandNumber, HandDate, HandResults " \
                          "FROM Hands " \
                          "WHERE HandNumber = %s AND HandDate = %s AND HandResults = %s)"
            cursor.execute(hand_insert, (self.hand_number, self.date, self.result,
                                         self.hand_number, self.date, self.result))
...
```

Restored original question as answer below solves the problem.

Comment: Specify the explicit columns to populate with the INSERT clause: `INSERT INTO Hands (HandNumber, HandDate, HandResults) ...` without that, the query will expect something for all columns. Or, alternatively, leaving the INSERT as-is, you can add NULL with the select: `SELECT NULL, HandNumber, HandDate, HandResults ...`

Comment: What @PaulT. said, plus you seem to be missing a `FROM` clause for your `SELECT`...

Comment: Having tried both of your suggestions, I am still getting the same error or an error claiming I'm not using enough parameters.

Comment: What Nick said, the first select is missing a `FROM` clause? ... is there some other table to check where the data does not exist?

Comment: You have 4 columns in table `hands` but you're only selecting 3 to insert in `SELECT %s, %s, %s`

Comment: From what I understand, the auto increment should take care of itself and not need to be selected. If I'm to select it, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of it being auto increment?

Comment: 'If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list, ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html ALSO in mysql you can override the auto_increment by providing a value

Comment: Incidentally, there's no point including many (or indeed, any) columns in a not exists statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested solution from comments was to explicitly write column names of the destination table. Hence:

```
...
HAND_HISTORY_DB_TABLES['Hands'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `Hands` ("
    "   `HandID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
    "   `HandNumber` int UNIQUE,"
    "   `HandDate` date NOT NULL,"
    "   `HandResults` float"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
...
            hand_insert = "INSERT INTO Hands (HandNumber, HandDate, HandResults) "\
                          "SELECT %s, %s, %s " \
                          "FROM Hands " \
                          "WHERE NOT EXISTS " \
                          "(SELECT NULL, HandNumber, HandDate, HandResults " \
                          "FROM Hands " \
                          "WHERE HandNumber = %s AND HandDate = %s AND HandResults = %s)"
            cursor.execute(hand_insert, (self.hand_number, self.date, self.result,
                                         self.hand_number, self.date, self.result))
...
```

The previous attempt failed because `Hands` table have 4 columns of `HandID, HandNumber, HandDate, HandResults`. With `INSERT INTO hands SELECT ...`, you're directly telling the query to insert into all 4 columns in the table `Hands` however the fields that you've selected in `SELECT ..` after the `INSERT` statement are only 3.